# How to disable and enable this checkbox slider button from angular code

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to disable and enable  this button inside an angular method is it possible if yes how

```
    <div class="payment-history">
  <div class="payment-history-item">
    <div class="payment-history-left">
      <div class="payment-history-title">Email</div>

    </div>
    <div class="payment-history-right ml-auto">
      <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [disabled] input to disable the checkbox and update isDisabled value from the controller

```
    <input [disabled]="isDisabled" = type="checkbox">
```